# typedef Size() of openCV

Tags: c++, opencv

This might be a really basic question but I am quite confused with this.

I can initialize an image of size (3266 x 2450) using the following line of code:

```
Mat image(   Size(3266, 2450) , CV_8UC3   );
```

but I need to do some test on several different types of images so, I want to do a `typedef`.

I need to have a `typedef` statement which can provide different size...something like following but even after searching, I could not find the correct syntax.

```
typedef cv::Size(2048, 1536) 3MP
typedef cv::Size(2464, 1632) 4MP
typedef cv::Size(3266, 2450) 8MP
```

**IMPORTANT:** If `typedef` is not a solution. Please suggest what could be the possible solution to use something like following for different images:

```
Mat image(   8MP , CV_8UC3   );
```

Comment: Identifiers can't start with a digit. Why typedef though, aren't these just values?

Comment: Use #define instead.

Comment: To use this with a `typedef` create a small template wrapper, taking the size values as template parameters.

Comment: @JonathanPotter: I tried to use `#define` but got confused with the syntax. Could you please tell me the syntax for that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot use `typedef` here because `Size` itself is a type, and `Size(x, y)` creates a value, not a type.  Use constants instead:

```
const cv::Size SIZE_3MP(2048, 1536);
const cv::Size SIZE_4MP(2464, 1632);
const cv::Size SIZE_8MP(3266, 2450);
```

Comment: thanks, it worked. I will accept the answer in few minutes.